# $\partial_\rho\bigg (\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\rho_0^2 J_1(q \rho_0)}{(a^2+(\rho_0-\rho)^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}} d\rho_0 \bigg)$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, bessel-functions, approximate-integration

Is there any method to calculate above integral? I need to know answer for different $q$'s. $J_1$ is Bessel function.

$\partial_\rho\bigg (\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\rho_0^2 J_1(q \rho_0)}{(a^2+(\rho_0-\rho)^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}} d\rho_0 \bigg)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a closed form for the indefinite integral, but the definite integral from $\rho=0$ to $\infty$ (for $a > 0$ and $q > 0$) is 
$$\frac{q}{6 a^2}  \left( aq{{I}_{0}\left(\frac{aq}{2}\right)}{{ K}_{1}
\left(\frac{aq}{2}\right)}-aq{{ I}_{1}\left(\frac{aq}2\right)}{{ K}_{0}
\left(\frac{aq}2\right)}-2\,{{ I}_{1}\left(\frac{aq}2\right)}{{ K}_{1}
\left(\frac{aq}2\right)} \right)
$$
where $I_j$ and $K_j$ are modified Bessel functions of the first and second kinds.

Comment: The integral could be written definitely, but I need a derivative also. Could you please check my edit to the question?